# Clean up a WIP site before launch

Tags: joomla-3.x, database

I've been working on my own template for work, and in the progress made different temporary articles, categories and menu names.

For the launch I'd like to clean it up as much as possible, resetting used aliases, so for the actual site, we don't have to use `about3` for alias, but can reset it to just 'about'

Is there a way, or should I just make a backup/clone and start fresh and copy everything over by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up articles, categories and menus by trashing them in Article Manager, Category Manager and Menu Manager.

You will also need to empty the Article, Category and Menu Trash before you can create a new article, category or menu with an alias that has already been used.

In Article Manager, Category Manager and Menu Manager, click on <kbd>Search Tools</kbd> and select <kbd>Trashed</kbd> to display the <kbd>**X** Empty Trash</kbd> option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, are you developing a template or designing a website? Template and content is completely separated in Joomla.

Either way, you can edit your aliases manually, I'm not aware of any automatic way to reset them.

[image: Menu item alias]

[image: Article alias]

If you have conflicting aliases (like your `about` page), you have to locate the article using `about` as alias, and either delete it or change the alias. Aliases are displayed in both Article Manager and Menu Manager, so it should be easy to locate using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in your browser. Once the `about` alias is removed, you can edit your new *About* page to use this alias.

**Article aliases within the same category and Menu aliases within the same menu level has to be unique.**

[image]